# React component re-renders endlessly with onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the onClick event of the button in result.js to render my Spinner component, and have so far (kind of) gotten it to do so. At the moment, Spinner mostly has some console.log() statements, and it keeps logging "Rendered spinner." endlessly after clicking the button, about once every second.
For the record, the returned paragraph isn't being displayed, but I haven't gotten around to debugging that yet. Also, I have excluded some code in Result.js that I think is irrelevant.

For now, I just want Spinner to only render once after pressing the button. Any tips?

result.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Spinner from "./spinner";

class UnboxResult extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showSpinner: false
    };
    this.handleUnboxClicked = this.handleUnboxClicked.bind(this);
  }

  handleUnboxClicked(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Inside handleUnboxClicked");
    this.setState({
      showSpinner: true
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <section className="opening">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <button onClick={this.handleUnboxClicked}>UNBOX</button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.showSpinner ?
              <Spinner items={this.props.unbox.items}/> :
              null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  unbox: state.unbox
}))(UnboxResult);
```

spinner.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Spinner extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log("Before super");
    super(props);
    console.log("Ran constructor.");
  }

  render(){
    console.log("Rendered spinner.");
    return(
    <p>Spinning..</p>
    );
  }
}
export default Spinner;
```

Comment: What is `items={this.props.unbox.items}` ? Remove it and you'll get the expected result

Comment: @TheReason Why would that solve the problem?

Comment: @TheReason The idea was to simply pass that specific 'props' on to the Spinner component. I tried removing it, but it made no difference. It still keeps logging the message endlessly.

Comment: @Pkn because `this.state.showSpinner` is true and you don't change the state to false. Add one of the lifecycle hook `componentWillUnmount` in spinner and you don't see that called at all.

Comment: @Mad-D Thanks for the hint, but could you elaborate a bit more? I'm completely new to React, and I'm not sure what to place inside componentWillUnmount. I assume this.state.showSpinner is unreachable from the Spinner component, but can I pass a direct reference to it?

Comment: @Pkn when does the spinner suppose to stop ? what is the criteria ? you can by passing a function and triggering the action in child

Comment: @Pkn when do you want to stop showing spinner ? what do you mean by showing it only once

Comment: @Mad-D The goal is to make the "UNBOX" button say something like "Unbox 1 of 4", and when the user presses it, the Spinner component is rendered, which shows an animation and then presents a "Continue" button. The user will then be taken back to UnboxResult, which will now say "Unbox 2 of 4". Then, when clicked, the Spinner is shown again, and so on. Kind of like a roulette wheel which can be spinned a certain amount of times.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you're showing which would re-render the spinner continuously. My guess is that whatever is rendering `UnboxResult` is constantly updating. I recommend investigating what's causing your components to constantly re-render. More info here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

Comment: Both components look good. You are using redux so probably the problem somewhere in the action or reducer. That's why i suggested removing `this.props.unbox.items`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a handler method to update the state from spinner

```
handleClick(){
  this.setState({
    showSpinner: true
  })
}
```

and in your render it will need to be passed as prop

```
<div className="row">
  {this.state.showSpinner ?
    <Spinner handleClick={this.handleClick}/> :
    null}
</div>
```

In your spinner component return you can trigger this using onclick

```
<button onClick = {this.props.handleClick} > Click </button>
```

This will allow you to update the state back in your parent, You might want to figure out how you would display the items one at a time in spinner and only set state to false when there is no items left to display.

Sorry if i misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Why does `Spinner` need a `handleClick` prop?